# How to retrieve data from nested loop in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have checked all queries form Stack over flow, but I couldn't understand.

```
 getLocations() {
    return this.db.collection('MotelLocations').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { data };
      }))
    );
  }
```

```
ds.getLocations().subscribe(a=> {
      this.locationData = JSON.stringify(a);
      console.log(this.locationData)
```

```
[{"data":{"location":"New Jersey"}},{"data":{"location":"New York"}}]
```

I need location name. That's all.

Comment: I am sorry about the late response. Just made it. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

The code is using the [RxJS map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) in combination with the [JavaScript Array#map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the emitted `actions` array into an array of data objects.

It might be easier to understand if you look at each transformation function separately since we have nested mapping going on.

RxJS `map` takes a projection function and applies it to each value emitted by the Observable:

```js
return this.db.collection('MotelLocations').snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(projectionFn) // <--- pass it a projection function
);
```

In this case, the emitted value is an `actions` array, so a simple (but useless) projection function that accepts the emitted value and simply returns it unchanged would look like this:

```js
function projectionFn(actions) {
  return actions;
}
```

It's important to keep in mind here that the projection function is applied to the array itself, not to each element of the array, because the array is what was emitted by the Observable.

The next step is to transform each element of the array. For that, the code is just using JavaScript's Array#map method. So your projection function becomes:

```js
function projectionFn(actions) {
  return actions.map(a => { // <--- plain old JavaScript Array#map
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { data }; // <--- shorthand for return { data: data };
  });
}
```

So Array#map here transforms the array of actions into an array of data objects. And that array of data objects is what the projection function is returning, passing it down the Observable pipe.

Looking at the mapping function, its `return` statement is using [ES2015 shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015). That allows you to replace this:

```js
const data = a.payload.doc.data();

return {
  data: data
};
```

with this:

```js
const data = a.payload.doc.data();

return {
  data
};
```

when the property name is the same as the variable name you're having it reference.

Now the finale...

Looking at the JSON you logged, it's apparent the `data` object you're extracting from each action is structured like this:

```js
const data = a.payload.doc.data();

// data = { location: 'New Jersey' }
```

So if you want an array of locations instead of an array of data objects, just have your mapping function return the location property rather than the entire `data` object.

So change this:

```js
return { data };
```

to this:

```js
return data.location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the longer explanation @MikeJ Glad we reached the same solution. :)

Comment: I did research found the answer fortunately but your explanation cleared my concept. Tysm for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
 getLocations() {
    return this.db.collection('MotelsInfo').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {... a.payload.doc.data() as {} };
      }))
    );
  }
```

In the return statement, I was missing `... a.payload.doc.data() as {}` then fetched data.the location gave me what I was looking for it. I am sorry about the late posting. But that helped me out.